# Sqlalchemy core: create a json_agg and json_buld_object query

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have not found any documentation on sqlalchemy to create `json_agg`, `json_build_object` and `json_build_array`. Should we need to write query as sql for these?

Comment: These are functions, so the are accessed like any other database function in sqlalchemy: `sqlalchemy.func.json_agg`.